# How do I pass a url to NSBundle for xml parsing with AEXML?

Tags: xml, swift, nsdata, nsxmlparser, nsbundle

I'm using [AEXML](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML) and would like to pass XML from a REST service into the AEXML parser. However, in the example code provided the author passes a *local* xml file into his parser. Based on the example provided I can't seem to figure out how to pass xml data that was received via URL.

I have tried capturing the url and parsing it with `NSXMLParser` before passing it to the bundler but that didn't work. I've also tried creating an NSData object from the URL stream. So it leads me to the question.

**How do I pass a url to NSBundle for xml parsing?**

Relevant code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // example from README.md
        if let xmlPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("example", ofType: "xml") {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: xmlPath) {

                // works only if data is successfully parsed
                // otherwise prints information about error with parsing
                var error: NSError?
                if let xmlDoc = AEXMLDocument(xmlData: data, error: &error) {

                    // prints the same XML structure as original
                    println(xmlDoc.xmlString)

                    // prints cats, dogs
                    for child in xmlDoc.root.children {
                        println(child.name)
                    }

                    // prints Optional("Tinna") (first element)
                    println(xmlDoc.root["cats"]["cat"].value)

                    // prints Tinna (first element)
                    println(xmlDoc.root["cats"]["cat"].stringValue)
```

if you need to see more code, you can view it on [GitHub here](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML/blob/master/AEXMLExample/ViewController.swift).

Comment: note: i posted this last night and thought I my issue was due to an Xcode but I deleted my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass URL containing remote data to AEXML, because it does not do networking, only XML parsing.

You should first create NSData from your URL and create AEXMLDocument from that data.

If you look inside the AEXMLExample project, you will find exact example for doing just that, and you can also try it with any URL if you run it in simulator:

```
@IBAction func tryRemoteXML(sender: UIButton) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: textField.text) {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
            var error: NSError?
            if let doc = AEXMLDocument(xmlData: data, error: &error) {
                var parsedText = String()
                // parse unknown structure
                for child in doc.root.children {
                    parsedText += child.xmlString + "\n"
                }
                textView.text = parsedText
            } else {
                let err = "description: \(error?.localizedDescription)\ninfo: \(error?.userInfo)"
                textView.text = err
            }
        }
    }
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: well... don't i feel silly. I had played with several XML parsers last night and for some reason when I opened your project up I went straight for the view controller. Ok, thanks tadija.